# Which runs first, install-upgrade script or data-upgrade script?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, upgrade-script, data-script

I'm upgrading a module to version lets say `0.1.3`. Say I have these files:

```
data/mymodule_setup/data-upgrade-0.1.2-0.1.3.php
sql/mymodule_setup/upgrade-0.1.2-0.1.3.php
```

Will the sql upgrade script run first? The data upgrade script requires a column that will be added in the other script, so if it's not there yet it will fail.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The order is

1. install
2. install upgrade script
3. data script
4. data upgrade script

More info can be found here: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

or http://www.sitepoint.com/magento-install-upgrade-data-scripts-explained/

Or thanks to @RickBuczynski the following link: http://vinaikopp.com/2014/11/03/magento-setup-scripts/

**Addition:** If you have modules that depend on each other, you should know that when several modules are installed/updated at once, first *all* normal upgrade scripts run, then *all* data upgrade scripts. Each in the order how the module are loaded, i.e. with regards to dependencies.

Comment: I have already read both those articles, but there isn't anything in them about the order of execution. Your answer makes sense, but can you confirm with evidence that this is the real order?

Comment: I'd also add this URL for reference: http://vinaikopp.com/2014/11/03/magento-setup-scripts/
Seems to be the best in-depth info I've ever read on the subject.

Comment: @Vic see the link from Rick.

Comment: @RickBuczynski wow, amazing article!

Comment: @RickBuczynski great article! Can you or JELLEJ add it to the answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Answer changed. But @RickBuczynski feel free to add your link so Vic can choose your answer :)

Comment: Nah, it's all good. All 3 resources are useful, depending on your level of experience with this area. I'll get my points some other time :-p

Answer (score 2):

the magento follow this order

1. install
2. install upgrade script
3. data script
4. data upgrade script

the interesting starts if

in 1st script you insert data (create website)

and in 2nd script you read that data (category finds website)

1. magento install scripts are run within one transaction
2. magento upgrade scripts are run in other transaction
3. the default mysql transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ

have fun